# Discord.py Help me

Tags: python-3.x

```
@client.listen("on_message")
async def on_message(message):
    userid = message.author.id
    Guild = message.guild
    Member = message.guild.owner
    if Member.mentioned_in(message.content):
        cursor = ownerpingtime.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT ownerpingtime FROM ownerpingtime WHERE client_id = " + str(userid))
        ownerpingtime.commit()
        alldata = cursor.fetchall()
        timedid : int = alldata[0][0]
        timetillban : int = 5 - int(timedid)
        if timedid == 1:
            await message.delete()
            await message.reply(f"{message.author}#{message.author.discriminator} ping this server owner `{timedid}` time, you have `{timetillban}` till you will be banned")
        if timedid > 1 and timedid < 10:
            await message.delete()
            await message.reply(f"{message.author}#{message.author.discriminator} ping this server owner `{timedid}` times, you have `{timetillban}` till you will be banned")
        if timedid == 10:
            await message.delete()
            await message.send(f"{message.author}#{message.author.discriminator} has banned from {Guild} by pinged guild owner 10 times")
            await message.author.send(f"You have banned from {Guild} by pinged guild owner 10 times")
```

And this is the error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\blabla\Desktop\All Things\Code File\Python\Discord.py\MineHardcore.py", line 168, in on_message
    if Member.mentioned_in(message.content):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mentioned_in'
```

## Help me. I turned on member intents and I want to check if guild owner mentioned in message.content then my bot remove it, send the notification and if they do 10 times then my bot ban them ( I used Python MySQL Connector )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is cheking for ping so you should modify your if statement and make it `if <@12345678901234> in message.content:` and replace `12345678901234` with the owner id.